# How can I add Buttons in Preference Page which extends FieldEditorPreferencePage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have one Preference Page which extending `FieldEditorPreferencePage`.I want align two `SWT` buttons just before `Restore Defaults` & `Apply` buttons as shown in the image.

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

When you look at the structure of the UI, you'll see that the preference page building code creates a container and then gives you this container to fill.

The container is a sibling of the container which contains the buttons "Restore Defaults" and "Apply" in the image. Since it's a sibling (i.e. the buttons and your buttons are *not* in the same container), you can't align your buttons to them (layout only works in the same container).

Now the simple solution would be to go to your parent and then search for the sibling container to add your buttons. But that would make the buttons stick around when the user leaves your preferences page. And if you're not careful, the user would get two more buttons each time he visits your page.

The alternative is to use a grid layout and add a container below your editors which spans all columns. Use a `Composite` for this. Configure this container to grow in both directions.

Assign a new grid layout to the inner container I1. Inside the container, add another container I2 which doesn't grow. Position it right/bottom.

Add your buttons to I2.

I.e. you have page contains I1 contains I2 contains buttons.